# how make SQL Update in crawler database in OpenSearchServer 1.4

Tags: database, search, web-crawler, server

1) we have configure a crawler with "sql select" to create the index and all is ok for this
we can crawl an use oss search.

we use use this request :

```
SELECT   concat(archive.dossier.numero,archive.cote_plan_classement.id) idsearch,  
        archive.dossier.titre,
        archive.dossier.numero,
        archive.dossier.type_id,
        archive.dossier.cote_id,
        archive.cote_plan_classement.id pc_code_id,
        archive.cote_plan_classement.label acpc_label,
        archive.cote_plan_classement.note acpc_note
FROM archive.dossier;
left outer join archive.cote_plan_classement
on archive.cote_plan_classement.id = archive.dossier.cote_id;
```

2) our problem is with the "sql update" request in the crawler
we have no idea to configure it

we want to update the index when a data change and just update the data, not all the index

can you help me?
have you a solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The "SQL Update" actually is for updating the database when the crawling process runs. You could for example choose to insert current date in a particular table for each crawling.

What we often do is configuring two crawling process:

- one full, which is run nightly or weekly
- one incremental, which is run very regularly. This process use a particular WHERE clause. For
  example for running a process that will only index data from the last
  day, for PostgreSQL : `SELECT ... WHERE mod_date > current_date - 1`
  (if column "mod_date" holds last modification date)

"SQL Update" is not used here.

On the other hand you could run your crawl process very very regularly and add a test in the WHERE where you would only get documents whose mod_date is after the date you inserting in a particular table during previous crawling, thanks to the "SQL Update" feature.

You could also choose to start the database crawling process by API each time a modification is made on your database. You will find on this page the documentation to run a database crawler by API: http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/faq/crawling/how_to_use_variables_with_database_crawler.md (you will also learn how to use variables, which could be very useful).

Alexandre